# How do I show that $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}/T$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Tags: group-theory

Here, $T = \{-1, 1\}$ and  $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is the multiplicative group of all the non-zero reals, and $\mathbb{R}^+$ is the multiplicative group of positive real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Can you think of a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ for which $T$ is the kernel?

Here is a more explicit suggestion if you need it:

> Consider the absolute value map on $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$.